# set subfolder in node-red mail module

Tags: email, node-red

I start playing with node-red and want to try the node-red mail module. Connection to INBOX is fine.

Now I want to select a other folder. In my mail account every folder is a subfolder of INBOX, but if I entered INBOX/folder node-red crashed and I have to change the flows.json to start the server again.

If I only enter the folder name I have still the same problem. I got the error message "Error: No mailbox is currently selected"

Answer (score 0):

Simple as possible. You have to set a . between folder, so it looks like INBOX.folder.